Navigating pages while using sockets.io
I clearly understand that when you refresh or your user goes to another page the original socket will be destroyed and a new socket created for the next page.
That's okay,  I can live with that.
My server is storing a few objects that have all the user info I need. When the user joins or leaves the first page, I store a few ID cookies on the client. When they open the next page, I read the cookies, send them to the server and the user is re-connected to their data on the server.
My question is how to I navigate thru pages.
I thought a simple
window.location.href="page2.html" 

on the client side would work, but I'm getting "cannot GET" errors. This may not even be the proper way to change pages using sockets. My clients could all be on different pages. How do I manage the navigation of my clients?
HTML Page
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style1.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/open-book.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" class="button" onclick="btnChgPage()" value="Change page">
  </body>
  <script src="/static/cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/game.js"></script>
  
</html>

Client JS
var socket = io();
console.log("Version 3");

socket.on('connect', function() {   
  console.log('connected');
});

function btnChgPage() {
  console.log("changing page"); 
  setCookie("name", "testingTommy", 15000)
  window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5000/page2.html';
}

Server JS
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = socketIO(server);

app.set('port', 5000);
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

// Routing
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
  console.log(request);
});

server.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log('Starting server on port 5000');
});


//===================================================
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  console.log("new connection");  
  
 //--------------------------------------------------- 
  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    /* for (const room of socket.rooms) {
      if (room !== socket.id) {
        socket.to(room).emit("user has left", socket.id);
        console.log(`user left ${room}`);
      }
    } */
    console.log("user left");
  });  
});

